# Conditional on Blade To Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I would like to transpose the conditional code below into the vue.js semantics

```
<table>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <tr>
            @foreach($sintese as $s)
                <td>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" name="chksintese" id="{{$s->cod_sintese_conversa}}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                        {{$s->descricao}}
                    </label>
                </td>

                @if ($loop->iteration % 10 == 0 && !$loop->last)
                    </tr><tr>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </div>
</table>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a "please code this for me" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can manage your data before binding to table

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#table',
    computed:{
        newItems: function (){
            var tempItem = [];
            var slice = 10;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.it.length/slice; i++) {
                tempItem.push(this.it.slice(i*slice, slice*(i+1)));
            }
            return tempItem;
        }
    },
    data: {
        it: [{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa1","descricao":"descricao1"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa2","descricao":"descricao2"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa3","descricao":"descricao3"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa4","descricao":"descricao4"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa5","descricao":"descricao5"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa6","descricao":"descricao6"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa7","descricao":"descricao7"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa8","descricao":"descricao8"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa9","descricao":"descricao9"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa10","descricao":"descricao10"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa11","descricao":"descricao11"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa12","descricao":"descricao12"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa13","descricao":"descricao13"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa14","descricao":"descricao14"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa15","descricao":"descricao15"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa16","descricao":"descricao16"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa17","descricao":"descricao17"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa18","descricao":"descricao18"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa19","descricao":"descricao19"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa20","descricao":"descricao20"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa21","descricao":"descricao21"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa22","descricao":"descricao22"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa23","descricao":"descricao23"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa24","descricao":"descricao24"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa25","descricao":"descricao25"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa26","descricao":"descricao26"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa27","descricao":"descricao27"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa28","descricao":"descricao28"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa29","descricao":"descricao29"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa30","descricao":"descricao30"},{"cod_sintese_conversa":"cod_sintese_conversa31","descricao":"descricao31"}]
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
<table id="table">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <tr v-for="items in newItems">
            <td v-for="item in items">
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" name="chksintese" :id="item.cod_sintese_conversa">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                    {{item.descricao}}
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</table>
```